# UITabBarItemPositioningFill

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar

I try to distribute Tab Bar buttons across the bottom of the iPad screen.

Apple :

> For the iPad user interface item, tab bar items are positioned closely adjacent to each other with a default width and inter-item spacing.
>
> @property(nonatomic) UITabBarItemPositioning itemPositioning;
>
> To force tab bar items to fill all space horizontally, specify the UITabBarItemPositioningFill constant for this property;

in .h

```
 @property(nonatomic) UITabBarItemPositioning itemPositioning;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize itemPositioning=UITabBarItemPositioningFill;
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what _is_ happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the value of the itemPositioning property to UITabBarItemPositioningFill. You don't do that in an @synthesize statement (so delete that line). You need something like this in viewDidLoad of the controller in the first tab,

self.tabBarController.tabBar.itemPositioning = UITabBarItemPositioningFill;